# What's the meaning of `accum` field in hprof's result?

Tags: java, hprof

When I running java with option:

```
-agentlib:hprof=cpu=times
```

The hprof's result is like:

```
CPU TIME (ms) BEGIN (total = 3093024) Thu Jan 28 14:57:36 2016
rank   self   accum    count trace  method
1      35.81% 35.81%       6 328434 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park
2      28.04% 63.85%      68 330338 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park
3      11.04% 74.88%   59675 326270 sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll
```

I'am wondering what's the meaning of `accum` filed?

Thanks.

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1547032?start=0&tstart=0 gives a hint

Comment: Thanks for your help, I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [hprof CPU TIMES](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1547032?start=0&tstart=0):

```
accum: includes the time for the entries that appear above this one in the list. The last entry will have an accum of 100%
```